# How do I Create a Workspace in Ubuntu 18.10 Minimal Install?

Tags: gnome-shell, 18.10, workspaces, minimal-install

I'm trying to create another workspace in my Ubuntu 18.10 minimal install machine and I cannot figure out how to create a new workspace.  Most websites say to hover your mouse on the right side of the activities screen, however this does not do anything:

[image: activities screenshot]

Do I need to install a workspace package or enable workspaces in settings?  How do I use a workspace from the basic 18.10 install?

Edit: As it turns out, this is the Applications screen.  Somehow, on the new install of 18.10, the Windows key + tab no longer opens the Activities screen (I believe in 16 it did) and instead mimics the alt + tab shortcut to switch windows.  The new way to open activities is to press the Windows key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the default Ubuntu Gnome desktop, simply click on the "Activities" button in the top left, and then mouse over to the right edge of your screen.  You will see all active workspaces plus one empty one.  To create new workspaces simply drag a window to an empty one, or to the space between two existing workspaces, and a new workspace will be created.  There will always been one empty workspace more than the ones you are actively using.

Comment: If you read my question and it says that there is no workspaces bar nor does it pop up when I drag my mouse to the edge of the screen, this is just adding words that are not very relevant.  I have used workspaces before, just not seeing them on this new install.

Comment: @Craig Perhaps you should read the answer thoroughly. This image you provided is **not** of the 'Activities' screen, but 'Show Applications' screen. 'Activities' screen is accessible by clicking the "Activities" button (as the answer said) or by pressing the <Super> key.

Comment: @pomsky This makes more sense now, thanks for the help.  For those that are looking, the shortcut for opening activities on an originally Windows laptop is fn + Windows key.

Comment: @Craig <fn> key usually not required, the default shortcut is the <Super> key (i.e. the key with Windows logo).

Comment: Also note if you don't have the additional workspace slot on the activities screen, head over to the settings -> multitasking -> work spaces and either enable dynamic or fixed work spaces with a set number if enabling fixed